# Setter in logback appender that is called after all the configuration is read from file

Tags: java, logback

In log4j there is a method [AppenderSkeleton.activateOptions](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html#activateOptions()) which is called after log4j has parsed the configuration file and called any associated setters.

Is there any similar method in logback `AppenderBase` which is called  after logback has parsed the configuration file and called the associated setters?

I am using the below dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you look at the javadoc, aka did you **research** this? Did you see the [`start()`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/AppenderBase.html#start()) method from the [`LifeCycle`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle.html) interface? Perhaps it can provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. I am using this by seeing the code of some appenders. I just want to confirm if this is equivalent of  `activateOptions` as the comment of `start` in javadoc does not mention anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a very similar concept on logback. It are the `start()` and 
`stop()` methods, part of the `LifeCycle` interface in the 
`ch.qos.logback.core.spi` package.

Most if not all logback components implement this interface.